# Hide an element (in this case button) with visibility

Tags: jquery, css, visibility

Wanted to hide a button while maintaining the space between buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','hidden');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','visible');});
}
```

Looked up for visibility CSS tag. But doesn't seem to work this way (or maybe i'm getting the .css() function wrong).

JS Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uyoezedy/2/ - syntax error(missing `)` at the end) + no jQuery included in the fiddle

Comment: you are missing `);` at the end of your code...

Comment: Check this `http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/7/`

Comment: Why don't you use just: $("#target").hide();

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery's `hide` and `show` which set visibility for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/12/

```
$(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').hide();});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').show();});
});
```

Behind the scenes `hide()` sets `display: none;` and `show()` sets `display: inline-block;`

**Notes:**

- `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` is a nice shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`
- Hide collapse up the space the element takes up
- Your original did not include jQuery (options on the left side of JSFiddle)
- Your DOM ready handler was not closed (missing `);`)

If you want to use `visibility`, so the space does not collapse, just fix the syntax error:

http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/13/

```
$(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','hidden');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','visible');});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You had an error in your js and also haven't referenced jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','hidden');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('visibility','visible');});
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
$( ".target" ).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery to the fiddle and, there was a simple syntax error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){
        $('#btn').css('visibility','hidden');
    });
    $('#show').click(function(){
        $('#btn').css('visibility','visible');
    });
})
```

Check the fiddle below
http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/6/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with 4 things:

1. Opacity
2. Display
3. Background-color
   4
   .hide show

Code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('display','none');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('display','block');});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('opacity','0');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('opacity','1');});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').css('background','transparent');});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').css('background','inherit');});
});



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hide').click(function(){$('#btn').hide();});
    $('#show').click(function(){$('#btn').show();});
     });
```

Hope I helped

Comment: `display` requires additional styling http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/15/ and `background` is not a good option: http://jsfiddle.net/uyoezedy/14/